# Why is it showing mongodb validation error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, m

mongoose schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-type-url');
const mobilesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        maxLength:100
    },
    price:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    desc:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    productLink:{type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Url},
    imageLink:{type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Url},
}, {timestamps: true})
const Mobiles = mongoose.model('Mobiles', mobilesSchema)
module.exports = Mobiles
```

controller

```
const Mobiles = require('../models/mobiles')
exports.createMobile = async (req, res) => {
    const {
        name, 
        price, 
        desc, 
        productLink, 
        imageLink
    } = req.body;
    try{
        const newMobile = new Mobiles();
        newMobile.name = name;
        newMobile.price = price;
        newMobile.desc = desc;
        newMobile.productLink = productLink;
        newMobile.imageLink = imageLink;
        await newMobile.save();
        res.json({
            successMessage: `${newMobile.name} added successfully`,
        })
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500).json({
            errorMessage: 'Mobile creation failed',
        })
    }

}
```

routes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mobileController = require('../controllers/mobiles')
const {authenticateJWT} = require('../middleware/authenticator')
router.post('/', authenticateJWT, mobileController.createMobile );
router.get('/', authenticateJWT, mobileController.readMobile)
module.exports = router;
```

API

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const createMobile = async(data)=>{
    const response = await axios.post('/api/mobiles', data)
    return response;
}
```

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const connectDB = require('./database/db');

const morgan = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const categoryRoutes = require('./routes/category');
const mobileRoutes = require('./routes/mobiles')
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser())
connectDB();
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/category', categoryRoutes);
app.use('/api/mobiles', mobileRoutes)
app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Client-side

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import isEmpty from 'validator/lib/isEmpty';
import {createMobile} from '../../api/mobiles'
import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import {Collapse, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { AlertMSG, SuccessMsg } from '../../helpers/message'
import {Loader} from '../../helpers/loader'
import {FaPlus} from 'react-icons/fa'

const AddMobile = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [mobile, setMobile] = useState('')
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')
    const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState('')
    const [mobileData, setMobileData] = useState({
        name:'',
        price:'',
        desc:'',
        productLink:'',
        imageLink:''
    })
    const {
        name,
        price,
        desc,
        productLink,
        imageLink
    } = mobileData
    const handleShow = () => setMobile(!mobile);
    const handleMobileChange = evt => {
        setErrorMessage('')
        setSuccessMessage('')
        setLoading(false)
        setMobileData({
            ...mobileData,
            [evt.target.name] : evt.target.value,
        })
    }
    const handleMessage = evt => {
        setErrorMessage('');
        setSuccessMessage('');
    }
    const handleMobileSubmit = evt => {
        setErrorMessage('');
        setSuccessMessage('');
        evt.preventDefault();
        if (isEmpty(name)){
            setErrorMessage('Name cannot be empty');
        }else if(isEmpty(price)){
            setErrorMessage('Price cannot be empty');
        }else if(isEmpty(desc)){
            setErrorMessage('Description cannot be empty');
        }else if(isEmpty(productLink)){
            setErrorMessage('Product Link cannot be empty');
        }else if(isEmpty(imageLink)){
            setErrorMessage('Image Link cannot be empty');
        }else{
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', name);
            formData.append('price', price)
            formData.append('desc', desc)
            formData.append('productLink', productLink)
            formData.append('imageLink', imageLink)
            createMobile(formData)
            .then((response) => {
                setMobileData({
                    name:'',
                    price:'',
                    desc:'',
                    productLink:'',
                    imageLink:''
                })
                setSuccessMessage(response.data.successMessage)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setErrorMessage(err.response.data.errorMessage)
            })
        }
    }
    return(
        <>
        <div className=" my-2" onClick={handleMessage}>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row pb-3">
                    <div className="col-md-12 my-2">
                    <Button color="success" className="btn btn-block" onClick={handleShow} style={{ marginBottom: '1rem' }}><FaPlus/> Add Mobile</Button>
                    <Collapse in={mobile}>
                        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
                            <div className="modal-content">
                                <form onSubmit={handleMobileSubmit}>
                                    <div className="modal-header bg-success text-white">
                                        <h5 className="modal-title"><FaPlus/> Add Mobile</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="modal-body my-2">
                                        {errorMessage && AlertMSG(errorMessage)}
                                        {successMessage && SuccessMsg(successMessage)}
                                        {loading ?(
                                            <div className='text-center'>{Loader()}</div>
                                        ):(
                                            <>
                                            <div className='form-group mb-2'>
                                                <label className='text-secondary'>Mobile Name</label>
                                                <input type='text' className='form-control' name='name' value={name} onChange={handleMobileChange}/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className='form-group mb-2'>
                                                <label className='text-secondary'>Mobile Price</label>
                                                <input type='text' className='form-control' name='price' value={price} onChange={handleMobileChange}/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className='form-group mb-2'>
                                                <label className='text-secondary'>Mobile Description</label>
                                                <input type='text' className='form-control' name='desc' value={desc} onChange={handleMobileChange}/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className='form-group mb-2'>
                                                <label className='text-secondary'>Product Link</label>
                                                <input type='text' className='form-control' name='productLink' value={productLink} onChange={handleMobileChange}/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className='form-group mb-2'>
                                                <label className='text-secondary'>Image Link</label>
                                                <input type='text' className='form-control' name='imageLink' value={imageLink} onChange={handleMobileChange}/>
                                            </div>
                                            </>
                                        )}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Collapse>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

export default AddMobile;

error is showing that
Error: Mobiles validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., price: Path `price` is required., desc: Path `desc` is required.
at ValidationError.inspect

```
(E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:47:26)
at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:731:31)
at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:295:10)
at formatWithOptionsInternal (internal/util/inspect.js:1958:40)
at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1842:10)
at Object.value (internal/console/constructor.js:306:14)
at Object.log (internal/console/constructor.js:341:61)
at exports.createMobile (E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\controllers\mobiles.js:17:17)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) 
errors:
name: ValidatorError: Path `name` is required.
at validate (E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1235:13)
at E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1218:7
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1163:14)
at E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2505:18
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) 
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'name',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
price: ValidatorError: Path `price` is required.
 at validate (E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1235:13)
at E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1218:7
at SchemaNumber.SchemaType.doValidate (E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1163:14)
at E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2505:18
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) 
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'price',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
desc: ValidatorError: Path `desc` is required.
at validate (E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1235:13)
at E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1218:7
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1163:14)
at E:\Affiliate\Elect1\Nucleus\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2505:18
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) 
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'desc',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
,
_message: 'Mobiles validation failed'

POST /api/mobiles 500 66.393 ms - 41
```

Comment: Any one please help me with this

Comment: Did you confirm whether you're receiving the post data or not? `console.log` your `req.body` and post it here.

Comment: no i am not receving any data

Comment: try block in the controller is not executing

Comment: what is the body you are sending?

Comment: see I have updated above

Comment: You are sending "name" and expecting "addName".

Comment: That's right @AmritaYadav. But `req.body` should still have all the correct variables. @Gowtham Did you console.log `req.body` ?

Comment: yes console.log(req.body) is showing {}

Comment: formdata usually needs to be processed differently - I'm assuming you have tried everything here? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-to-process-post-data-in-node-js

Comment: it will be easier for everyone if you could put this as a github repo or fiddle or something...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you haven't set body parser to your express app.
Wherever you're initialing your express `app`, add this line after initializing:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

For example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// add this line
app.use(express.json());
```

`req.body` should contain all the variables now.

Comment: can you post your entry point file, where your server is being initialized?

Comment: try shifting `app.use(express.json());` to above `app.use(cors());` and see if it allows body to parse.